# Anonymous Authentication with Custom Controller

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to implement a custom controller in Acumatica for development purposes. But I cant seem to figure out how to sidestep Acumatica auth and allow access without authentication.

Here is my Controller:

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/using-asp-net-web-api-mvc-with-acumatica/

```
    [RoutePrefix("test")]
    public class TestController: ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route()]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IHttpActionResult PerformAction()
        {
            return Ok("Actions Available");
        }
}
```

And here is my startup

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}

public class ServiceRegistration : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Startup.Configuration);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

But when I send a GET to {baseUrl}/test in Postman, it returns 401 unauthorized. If I open my browser, log in and go to that same route, I recieve "actions available"

What am I missing to allow anonymous Auth on a custom WebApi Controller?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the `BasicAuthorizationAttribute` on your controller?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I will copy your code for it and try with

Comment: Actually there is a cleaner way, see answer

Comment: My code had a bug in it. It basically won't allow anonymous access because of the if statements on the line 26 and line 32. It ignores the fact that the allowanonymous can be true

Comment: Take a look at what I wrote for the answer, the platform guys gave me a better way

Comment: That way you may affect everything and not only your controller if I understand correctly

Comment: I tested it, it only sets anonymous to {baseAcumaticaURL}/sourcecontrol which is my custom endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization can be customized inside the Autofac module in the extension library. Reference PX.Export, PX.Hosting (this was done for 2021R1)

```
public class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}

public class ServiceRegistration : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Startup.Configuration);
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

// Configuration of Authorize here
        builder.Configure<AuthenticationManagerOptions>(options =>
            options.AddLocation("sourcecontrol").WithAnonymous());
    }
}
```